# How to get progress of streaming query after awaitTermination?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I am new to spark and was reading few things about monitoring the spark application. Basically, I want to know how many records were processed by spark application in given trigger time and progress of query. I know 'lastProgress' gives all those metrics but when I'm using awaitTermination with 'lastProgress' it always returns null.

```
 val q4s = spark.readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", brokers)
  .option("subscribe", topic)
  .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
  .load()
  .writeStream
  .outputMode("append")
  .option("checkpointLocation", checkpoint_loc)
  .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("10 seconds"))
  .format("console")
  .start()

  println("Query Id: "+ q4s.id.toString())
  println("QUERY PROGRESS.........")
println(q4s.lastProgress);
q4s.awaitTermination();
```

Output:

```
Query Id: efd6bc15-f10c-4938-a1aa-c81fdb2b33e3
QUERY PROGRESS.........
null
```

How can get progress of my query while using awaitTermination or how can I keep my query continuously running without using  awaitTermination?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

#### Using dedicated runnable thread

You can create a dedicated Thread continuously printing the last progress of your streaming query.

First, define a runnable Monitoring class which prints out the last Progress every 10 seconds (10000ms):

```scala
class StreamingMonitor(q: StreamingQuery) extends Runnable {
  def run {
    while(true) {
      println("Time: " + Calendar.getInstance().getTime())
      println(q.lastProgress)
      Thread.sleep(10000)
    }
  }
}
```

Second, implement this into your application code as below:

```
val q4s: StreamingQuery = df.writeStream
  [...]
  .start()

new Thread(new StreamingMonitor(q4s)).start()

q4s.awaitTermination()
```

#### Looping over query status

You could also have a while loop on the status of the query:

```scala
val q4s: StreamingQuery = df.writeStream
  [...]
  .start()

while(q4s.isActive) {
  println(q4s.lastProgress)
  Thread.sleep(10000)
}

q4s.awaitTermination()
```

#### Alternative Solution using StreamingQueryListener

An alternative solution to monitor your streaming query would be to use the `StreamingQueryListener`. Again, first define a Class extending the `StreamingQueryListener`:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.{StreamingQueryListener, StreamingQueryProgress}
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryListener.QueryProgressEvent


class MonitorListener extends StreamingQueryListener {

  override def onQueryStarted(event: StreamingQueryListener.QueryStartedEvent): Unit = { }

  override def onQueryProgress(event: QueryProgressEvent): Unit = {
    println(s"""numInputRows: ${event.progress.numInputRows}""")
    println(s"""processedRowsPerSecond: ${event.progress.processedRowsPerSecond}""")
  }

  override def onQueryTerminated(event: StreamingQueryListener.QueryTerminatedEvent): Unit = { }
}
```

then registering it with your SparkSession:

```scala
spark.streams.addListener(new MonitorListener)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to start a separate thread with the reference to the streaming query to monitor (say `q4s`) and pull the progress regularly.

The thread that started the query (the main thread of your Spark Structured Streaming application) is usually `awaitTermination` so the daemon threads of the streaming queries it started could keep running.

Comment: Thanks Jacek! I spent few hours trying to implement what you suggested but was not able to get there. Can you please point to a link where something similar is demonstrated.Thanks again!

Comment: I'd start from https://dzone.com/articles/guide-to-java-8-concurrency-using-executors