# pyspark structured streaming not updating query metrics with query.lastProgress or other standard metrics

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

I'm trying to add logging to my pyspark structured streaming application in order see the progress and statistics about each micro-batch processed. The writestream method uses a foreach writer to write the rows from the dataframe to a postgres database. I'm using `.lastProgress` and other standard metrics offered by pyspark for logging. The writestream method and my attempt to log are shown below.

```
query_1 = eventsDF \
    .writeStream \
    .foreach(writer) \
    .outputMode("append") \
    .option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/checkpoint_a/") \
    .trigger(processingTime="5 seconds") \
    .start()


query_progress =  query_1.lastProgress
print("progress ", query_progress)
print("status ", query_1.status)
print("active ", query_1.isActive)

query_1.awaitTermination()
```

The results from my first loop are:

```
progress  None
status  {'message': 'Initializing sources', 'isDataAvailable': False, 'isTriggerActive': False}
active  True
```

However, further batches processed as event data arrives do not result in any more logging messages. I would expect that the logging messages would be emitted after each micro-batch processed in the streaming job.

I appreciate any advice or guidance. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All code between the `start` and the `awaitTermination` get executed only once. Only the code between `load` and `start` get executed contiuously on every query trigger.

According to the book "Spark - The definitive Guide" this way of monitoring is meant to run inside your application. However, for standalone application, you usually do not have a shell attached to run arbitrary code. In the book they recommend to "expose [the query] status by implementing a monitoring server, such as a small HTTP server that listens on a port and returns `query.status` when it gets a request.

Therefore, you need to create a dedicated runable thread that frequently calls the monitoring API of the query. I am really not familiar with Python, but it will essentially look like below:

```py
# import the threading module 
import threading  
  
class thread(threading.Thread):  
    def __init__(self, query):  
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)  
        self.query = query  
  
        # helper function to execute the threads 
    def run(self):  
        print("progress ", query.lastProgress);
```

Having done this, you need to place it between `start` and `awaitTermination`:

```py
query_1 = eventsDF \
    [...]
    .start()

monitoring = thread(query_1)

query_1.awaitTermination()
```

In stead of a dedicated thread you could also loop over the status of the query using `while(query_1.isActive)`.

#### For Scala users:

[How to get progress of streaming query after awaitTermination?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54436822/how-to-get-progress-of-streaming-query-after-awaittermination/65188414#65188414)